# Scheme function as parameter

Tags: scheme

the program is supposed to use

```
(define (sum f n)
  (if (= n 0)
      (f 1)
      (+ (f n) (sum f (- n 1)))))
(define (harm-term k)
  (/ 1 k))
(define (harm-sum n)
  (sum (harm-term 1) n))
```

to create a function called `harm-sum` that calculates the sum of harmonic series. But I keep getting the error
application:

```
    not a procedure;
     expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments

  given: 3
  arguments...:
```

for the sum function.

Comment: Did this solve your issue?

Answer (score 2):

```
(define (sum f n)
  (if (= n 0)
      (f 1)
      (+ (f n) (sum f (- n 1)))))
(define (harm-term k)
  (/ 1 k))
(define (harm-sum n)
  (sum (harm-term 1) n))
```

The way that you are eventually calling sum is wrong because you call sum with `(harm-term 1)` as the parameter that you are expecting a function for. `(harm-term 1)` clearly evaluates to a 1.

This means that when it is used later in sum as the parameter `f` it makes no sense (i.e. you eventually call `(1 1)`)

You should be doing something like this:

```
(define (sum f n)
  (if (= n 0)
      (f 1)
      (+ (f n) (sum f (- n 1)))))
(define (harm-term k)
  (/ 1 k))
(define (harm-sum n)
  (sum harm-term n)) ; the difference is the function itself is passed instead of the value the function returns for 1
```